# A Bessel fuction identity: $z(J_{n-1}(z)+J_{n+1}(z))=2nJ_n (z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I found this problem in the book *Complex Analysis* by Christian Berg, and I got stuck at this point.

I have shown the first part, which is, that the Laurent series of the function $$f(w)=\exp\left(\frac{z}{2} \left(w-\frac{1}{w}\right)\right) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_n(z)w^n,\quad w \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\},$$
where $$J_n(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(z\sin t-nt)}dt=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\pi \cos(z\sin t-nt)dt,\quad n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
denotes the Bessel function of order $n$.

Now in the second part I have to show that $z(J_{n-1}(z)+J_{n+1}(z))=2nJ_n (z)$.

I don't even have a real approach to this. Any help, and other ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Show that $\cos (z\sin t - (n - 1)t) + \cos (z\sin t - (n + 1)t) = 2\cos (z\sin t - nt)\cos t$. Then use this to show that the problem is equivalent to showing that $$
\frac{2}{\pi }\int_0^\pi  {(z\cos t - n)\cos (z\sin t - nt){\rm d}t}  = \frac{2}{\pi }\int_0^\pi  {\frac{{\rm d}}{{{\rm d}t}}\sin (z\sin t - nt){\rm d}t} 
$$ is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove
$$
z(J_{n-1}(z)+J_{n+1}(z))=2nJ_n (z) .
\tag1$$
We know
$$
\exp\left(\frac{z}{2} \left(w-\frac{1}{w}\right)\right) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_n(z)w^n.
\tag2$$
Fix a complex number $z$.  Write
$$
f(w) = \exp\left(\frac{z}{2} \left(w-\frac{1}{w}\right)\right) .
\tag3$$

Work with that generating function.
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_n(z)nw^{n-1}= f'(w)
\\
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} 2nJ_n(z)w^{n}=2wf'(w)
\\
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{n-1}(z)w^{n}
=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{n}(z)w^{n+1} = wf(w)
\\
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} zJ_{n-1}(z)w^{n}
= zwf(w)
\\
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{n+1}(z)w^{n}
=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_{n}(z)w^{n-1} = \frac{f(w)}{w}.
\\
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} zJ_{n+1}(z)w^{n}
= \frac{zf(w)}{w}.
$$
So $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
zwf(w) + \frac{zf(w)}{w} = 2wf'(w) .
$$
Now recall $(3)$.  It suffices to prove
$$
zw \exp\left(\frac{z}{2} \left(w-\frac{1}{w}\right)\right)
+\frac{z}{w}\exp\left(\frac{z}{2} \left(w-\frac{1}{w}\right)\right)
=
2\frac{d}{dw}\exp\left(\frac{z}{2} \left(w-\frac{1}{w}\right)\right)
$$
This is merely an elementary calculus exercise.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped:)